# How to create directories in SQL?

Tags: sql

If it is possible in SQL to create directories and subdirectories in sql? 
I want to arrange my daily work in daywise folders?

Comment: but why didnt u googled your question https://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=sql%20create%20directories&oq=create%20directories%20sql&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2j69i60.6020j0j7

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: No! ANSI SQL has no such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It`s possible for sure, you can read it [here for oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm). As mention here ANSI SQL doesn't have such possibility

This way can be created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY bfile_dir AS '/usr/bin/bfile_dir';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Oracle, you could use the [`CREATE DIRECTORY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm) statement in SQL to create a directory.

```
CREATE (OR REPLACE) DIRECTORY directory_name AS path_name;
```

EDIT: As @jarlh mentioned:

> ANSI SQL has no such functionality.

Comment: Note that when no dbms is specified, ANSI SQL is default when answering.

Comment: Sorry, I'll change my answer. Is it fine now @jarlh?